# Lost SMS when iPhone screen auto-locked

Tags: iphone, ios

I've been having this issue several times: I'm writing a lengthy SMS, suddenly stop to do something else, and later come back with the auto-locked screen.

When I unlock my iPhone, the SMS I was writing is gone.

Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: Tested it on my iPhone 5s running on iOS 10.3 beta (14E5230e). Can't reproduce. Try a soft reset holding lock + home button for several seconds until apple logo shows up. Try to reproduce that problem; write a message and wait for the lock screen. Please give some feedback whether or not the problem persists. Edit: also tell us what you already tried and which iPhone on which version of iOS you are using.

Comment: Please tell us which iPhone and iOS version you are using exactly.

Comment: I have iphone 7 running ios 10.3.2 and have had this happen more times than I care to count. It just happened for the umpteenth time and I finally went searching for Answers!! :-( The scenario is that the auto-lock screen happens and after unlocking with pin or fingerprint (no matter the difference) the message I was composing (Always with a picture attachment) and some lengthy not quickly reproduced text (say 10 sentences) is MISSING!

Comment: Any pause in the typing such as using another computer to check or validate something you were typing in the email and come back seconds later to the iPhone it is locked and after unlocking it's as if you were in a time warp and back to 10 mins ago when you were thinking about emailing that picture you just took....the only thing you know is that the picture you took to start the email process still appears in Photos as the last picture taken...But No email message!